# segmentation fault in feof(FILE *) inbuilt Function

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault, file-pointer

```
void suffix_strip(FILE *fp)
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char word[20],ch;
    int len;
    int i=0,j;
    fp1=fopen("sstrip.txt","a+");
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        ch=fgetc(fp);
        if(ch!='\n' && ch!='\0' && ch!=' ' && ch!='.')
        {
            word[i]=ch;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            word[i]='\0';
            i=0;
            len=strlen(word);
            if(len>3)
            {
                if(word[len-3]=='i' && word[len-2]=='n' && word[len-1]=='g')
                {
                    word[len-3]='\0';
                }
                else if(word[len-2]=='e' && word[len-1]=='d')
                {
                    word[len-2]='\0';
                }

                fputs(word,fp1);

                if(count==0)
                {
                    in[count]->freq=1;
                    strcpy(in[count]->word,word);
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(j=0;j<count;j++)
                    {
                        if(strcmp(in[j]->word,word)==0)
                        {
                            in[j]->freq++;
                            goto x1;
                        }
                    }
                    in[count]->freq=1;
                    strcpy(in[count]->word,word);
                    count++;
                    x1:
                        printf("");

                }
                fputc(' ',fp1);
            }
            else
            {
                fputs(word,fp1);
                if(count==0)
                    {
                    in[count]->freq=1;
                    strcpy(in[count]->word,word);
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                for(j=0;j<count;j++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(in[j]->word,word)==0)
                    {
                        in[j]->freq++;
                        goto x2;
                    }
                }
                in[count]->freq=1;
                strcpy(in[count]->word,word);
                count++;
                x2:
                    printf("");

            }
            fputc(' ',fp1);
        }

    }

    }
    display();
```

}

/*

In the above Function when i enter the While loop checking the condition

while(!feof(fp))

the DevC++ IDE running MinGW GCC throws a segmentation fault,but the same code when run on VC++ 6.0 the code runs successfully without any error.
what might be the problem???
is it because i am passing the file pointer as an argument???
of the GCC compiler has some other conventions for the EOF representation??? 
if it's because of the argument passing then what might be correct way to get it solved using the same manner of parameter passing (i.e passing the file pointer)?? 
*/

Comment: Dev-C++ is incredibly outdated. I would recommend switching to MSVC on Windows (it's free) or if you really want to use MinGW, learn to use a command line interface (i.e. MSYS) and a simple editor (sublime text?) to write code (look at CodeBlocks for an alternative IDE, however).

Comment: Remove anything in your `while()` loop except for `ch=fgetc(fp);` and see if the issue remains. I bet that you exceed some array boundaries which messes up your stack (including the `FILE *fp` argument).

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the file open succeeds. Perhaps you're passing `NULL` to `feof()`.
2. Don't call `feof()` before doing I/O, *only* call it once I/O has failed.
3. `fgetc()` returns an `int`, *not* a `char`. This is because it can also return the special value `EOF` which is not a character.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `word[]` overflows. If you want to truncate words, change

```
            word[i]=ch;
            i++;
```

to

```
            if (i < sizeof word - 1) word[i++] = ch;
```

.